# Why do I have the wrong animation for right sidenav in materialize.css?

Tags: jquery, materialize

i wonder why I have a "left" animation for my right defined sidenav in materialize.css.
look at that gif:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    });

//Here my right sidebar with a parameter "edge: right". Still wrong animation for it?
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#slide-out2').sidenav({
           edge: 'right',
           draggable: false
       });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the CSS code involved so that other Stack Overflow contributors can assist.

Comment: Hey, I deleted all CSS code that I have in my app and only left materialize.css, so the problem remained the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly your issue is that the first function initializes ALL sidenavs with no modification (`edge:'left'` as default), and the second one re-initializes with the modification, so a potential conflict. In this case I would use two separate inits:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left-nav').sidenav();
    $('#right-nav').sidenav({
       edge: 'right',
       draggable: false
   });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/ExPPXmj) using vanilla JS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have tried, however the animation is still played from the left...

Comment: Problem solved, I used animation.css somewhere in my js code where sidenav class had an "appear from the left" animation. Was difficult to find that but it was the reason. Thanks again